# Защита и нападение

Tags: безопасность

Доброго времени суток.
Поделитесь качественным материалом по изучению безопасности (веб и устройств).
Спасибо.

Comment: Начните с этого http://catalystone.blogspot.ru/2016/01/blog-post_14.html

Comment: Ройте на тему "[социальная инженерия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F) (Social Engineering)". Человек (с его доверчивостью, ленью и т.п.) -- это наиболее уязвимое звено в системе.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, т.к. автор потратит время на прочтение всех статей про существующие уязвимости в Web, а у него могут просто сервера из дата-центра стырить... Хотите познать уязвимости, изучайте технологию или инструмент и кейсы нестандартного использования, из-за которых рождаются уязвимости.

Comment: Начинать надо с ассемблера, что бы действительно понимать, как работают компьютеры. Потом переходить к высокоуровневым языкам, начиная с C/C++, паралельно изучая ОС unix (linux). потом еще пару десятков языков программирования, мало ли на каком языке окажется написан код в котором надо искать уязвимости. А уже с таким багажом вы сможете понимать на чем основана та или иная уязвимость

Answer (score 4):

Если Вас интересуют фундаментальные знания по данной области, рекомендую спец. курс мгу:

- [Спецкурсы лаборатории Безопасности информационных систем (ЛБИС) ВМК МГУ](http://course.secsem.ru/)

Внизу есть две ссылки:

- [lections:](http://course.secsem.ru/lections) материалы лекций (слайды, аудиозаписи)
- [biblio:](http://course.secsem.ru/biblio) рекомендуемая литература

Обращаю внимание это фундаментальная информация, она не устареет через год , два - а только тогда когда придумают и внедрят новый протокол для вэба, например.

**Что нужно учить:**

- УК РФ и преступления в сфере информационных технологий;
- Модели угроз, их виды, объекты исследований:

  - *Антропогенные источники угроз;*
  - *Техногенные источники угроз*;
  - *Стихийные источники угроз;*
- Знакомство с Linux. Введение в Kali Linux Rolling Edition 2016 и обзор стандартного инструментария;
- Разведка и сбор информации;
- Сканирование сети;
- Поиск и эксплуатация уязвимостей:

  - *Эксплуатация web-уязвимостей, введение в Burp Suite, знакомство с OWASP     Top-10;*
  - *Безопасность сетевой инфраструктуры;*
  - *Анализ защищенности беспроводных сетей;*
  - *Введение в Metasploit Framework;*
  - *Обход проактивных систем защиты;*
- Введение в социальную инженерию.

Очень рекомендую хорошую книгу специалиста-практика - **johnny long - google hacking for penetration testers**